# appending <a href> to keywords in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, there are some keywords that i want to pick out and assign a link to them dynamically.

How should i go about in doing this?

Let's say i have something like this;

```
<p>ruby, rails, php, python, django and sinatra</p>
```

and i would like to assign links to keywords like ruby and python, so the end results should look like this;

```
<p><a href="http://www.ruby-lang.org">ruby</a>, rails, php, <a href="http://www.python.org">python</a>, django and sinatra</p>
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want the assignment happen in the backend or front-end? Because it would be a different story.

Comment: @Josh Stodola... not really a useful comment. In fact, if that was a real answer it would get downvoted.

Comment: @Josh Stodola: He did specify *dynamically*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it, assuming you only want to link whole words:

```
html = "<p>ruby, rails, php, python, django and sinatra</p>"

word_links = { "ruby"   => "http://www.ruby-lang.org",
               "python" => "http://www.python.org" }

html.gsub(/\w+/) do |word|
  word_links[word] ? "<a href=\"#{word_links[word]}\">#{word}</a>" : word
end
```

If the text you are operating on is rather large, but the list of words you want to link is pretty small, this may be optimized a little by doing substitution on matching words only:

```
html.gsub(/\b(#{word_links.keys.join('|')})\b/,
          "<a href=\"#{word_links[$1]}\">#{$1}</a>")
```

Just make sure you don't have any keywords that can appear inside an opening tag (like inside an attribute value for example, which would break completely with this solution.) For a truly robust solution you will have to use a proper HTML parser and just replace content text.

Comment: +1 for dealing with whitespace. I could swear there was a gem that does this but I can't find it!

Comment: thanks! I'm using this implementation but using each_pair instead of gsub.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it on the server side before the content is rendered to the browser then you can do it like

```
str = "<p>ruby, rails, php, python, django and sinatra scruby rubysd 12ruby'; ruby </p>"

link_hash = {'ruby' => "<a href = 'http://www.ruby-lang.org'>ruby</a>", 'python' => "<a href='http://www.python.org'>python</a>" }

link_hash.each_pair do |key, value|
  str = str.gsub(/\b#{key}\b/, value)
end

str #=> "<p><a href = 'http://www.ruby-lang.org'>ruby</a>, rails, php, <a href='http://www.python.org'>python</a>, django and sinatra scruby rubysd 12ruby'; <a href = 'http://www.ruby-lang.org'>ruby</a> </p>"
```

Comment: This will insert links where the keywords appear within longer words as well, which might or might not be desired. Imagine one of the keywords being "C", for instance.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat: Then you won't catch words at the start or end of the string, or with adjacent punctuation and linebreaks. Use \b to check for word boundaries in a regexp.

Comment: @DJTripleThread @Lars Haugseth thanks for pointing that out. I have now modified my answer to include the word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use text replacement? Replace "ruby" with "<a href="http://ruby-lang.org">ruby</a>", and done.
See the String.replace in the javascript reference .

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be particularly fancy, I think you could use an after filter:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :link_stuff

  protected

  def link_stuff
    # You'd want to do this more carefully, so as to only get "ruby"s in text, 
    # not in tags etc.
    response.body.gsub(/ruby/, "<a href = 'http://www.ruby-lang.org'>ruby</a>")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

first get the values as an array (or list) 
Ex: ruby 
    php
    python etc..

send this array to a helper

def link_builder(arr)
   html_string = ""

for element in arr

```
 check whether your word needs a wrapper. you might want to do a table check 

 if warpper_needed?

    html_string = html_string + <a href='link'>elment</a>
 else
    html_string = html_string + <p>element</p>
 end
```

end

html_string

end

Hope you got the idea, (this might not work as it is)

cheers,
sameera